# Como fazer um botão redondo usando xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xaml

Esse código não está funcionando dentro de um Grid como layout

```
<Button x:Name="btnTeste" Text="Click Me!!" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Black" BorderRadius="50" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" TextColor="White"/>
```

O que devo fazer para ele ficar redondo. Tentei fazer um BoxView redondo também e não consegui fazer.

Answer (score 0):

O `BorderRadius` no XAML faz isso. Ex:

```
<Button BorderRadius="10"/>
```